# How to offload the 1HZ tick in dyntick mode?

Tags: linux, kernel

It seems in kernel 4.19 and 4.20, the residual 1Hz tick can be offloaded to work queues in dyntick mode. But to achieve that exactly?

I tried to achieve that by doing below:

1. Set  CONFIG_NOHZ_FULL=y, CONFIG_RCU_FAST_NO_HZ=y, CONFIG_RCU_NOCB_CPU=y
2. Set boot parameters: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=nohz,domain,1-3 nohz=on nohz_full=1-3  rcu_nocbs=1-3 intel_pstate=disable irqaffinity=0 nmi_watchdog=0 nosoftlockup
3. Modify /sys/devices/virtual/workqueue/cpumask to 1
4. systemctl stop irqbalance
5. Turn off turbo mode, P state, and hythreading in BIOS

However, the 1HZ tick is still there when running a task on CPU 1 or 2.

I also tested the dyntick mode with the tool given in https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/frederic/dynticks-testing/. It outputs a lot of:

```
tick_stop: success=0 dependency=SCHED.
```

What did I miss to offload the 1 HZ tick?