# Puzzlement on NOHZ_FULL functionaility in Linux 4.18.20

Tags: linux, timer, performance-testing, interrupt

I am running RT test in X86 with Linux-4.18.20.
My kernel cmdline is configured as

```
 irqaffinity=0-5 isolcpus=nohz,domain,6-7 nowatchdog intel_idle.max_cstate=0 rcu_nocbs=6-7 rcu_nocb_poll=0-5 audit=0 selinux=0 nmi_watchdog=0 mce=ignore_ce transparent_hugepage=never clocksource=tsc tsc=reliable skew_tick=1 intel_iommu=on intel_pstate=disable nosoftlockup nohz_full=6-7
```

And I also did 'echo f > /sys/devices/virtual/workqueue/cpumask, sysctl -w vm.stat_interval=120'.
I am using ftrace to check the APIC timer interrupt occurrence when a SCHED_FIFO RT process is running in CPU7 explicitly.

I am puzzled when I dumped the ftrace on CPU7.
When the RT process calls a usleep (100) in a loop, there will be some 'extra' timer interrupts like below.

```
<idle>-0     [007] d...  1893.433243: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dN..  1893.433367: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs.  1893.433370: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt  <---
<idle>-0     [007] d...  1893.433482: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
......
<idle>-0     [007] d...  1893.765135: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] d...  1893.765245: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dN..  1893.765367: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs.  1893.765370: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt  <---
<idle>-0     [007] d...  1893.765480: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
```

If I remove the 'usleep', there is NO timer interrupt shown in Ftrace in CPU7, so I think NOHZ_FULL is working.   But why there are some *unexpected* timer interrupts?

The /proc/sched_debug shows my RT process is running on CPU7 with priority 99 of SCHED_FIFO.
It seemed the extra interrupts are from somewhere in Linux, but how can I totally remove them?
There are several similar questions in SO, like [How to offload the 1HZ tick in dyntick mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55061939/how-to-offload-the-1hz-tick-in-dyntick-mode) and [Completely eliminating the timer tick in modern Linux >=5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60322119/completely-eliminating-the-timer-tick-in-modern-linux-5-0) but I have not got the answer to my question.

<--- Edit below --->
I checked if the interval of 2 consequent timer interrupts is less than 100 us, and I got following interesting output,

```
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.037658: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.037660: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.045660: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.045662: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.053661: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.053664: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.089658: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.089661: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.097660: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.097663: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.121659: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.121661: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.129658: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.129661: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
--------
<idle>-0     [007] dN.. 15093.137659: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
<idle>-0     [007] dNs. 15093.137662: smp_apic_timer_interrupt <-apic_timer_interrupt
==============================
```

Taking the last 3 pairs as example.
The interval of the first line in these 3 pairs is about 8000us (8ms)! My Linux is configured with HZ = 250 (4ms), so it seemed that the HZ tick jumped in my loop, is this expected? Can we totally disable the HZ tick in the isolated CPUs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is from the Linux kernel tickless design.
When a single process A occupies an isolated CPU, and calls something like usleep()/sleep() which will trigger process switching (between A and idle).
Linux kernel will schedule the residue tick in this case.
If the process A is looping infinitely, no process switching happens on the CPU, no chance for idle to enter/exit, this will NOT trigger the residue tick.

I found the root cause, but I am still looking for a way to get the real tickless kernel as NOHZ_FULL describes......

I think Linux kernel could be optimized to a real NOHZ_FULL for above case, which is very important for RT workload in virtualization.